# how can mapwingis read data of a line shape file?

Tags: vb.net

I build an application with vb.net using mapwingis active x control tool
within i open a line shape file in axmap. All i want is to make mapwingis reads data of a line shape file which created by arcgis the data is diameters of these lines

Comment: Did you look at any of the examples: http://www.mapwindow.org/documentation/mapwingis4.9/examples.html

Comment: yes and could open the shape file i want to open the dbf file so as to read the data of the lines

Comment: Have a look at this example: http://www.mapwindow.org/documentation/mapwingis4.9/_edit_attributes_8cs-example.html